# Ratio between conduction current and displacement current

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waves

First, recall that the Maxwell displacement current for a plane wave is
$$ \vec{\jmath}_D = \epsilon\partial_t \vec{E} = \epsilon\partial_t \left[\vec{E}_{0} \cos\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} - \omega t\right)\right] = \epsilon \omega \vec{E}, $$
and then we know that the conduction current $\vec{\jmath}_{C}$ is related to $\vec{E}$ from Ohm's law
$$ \vec{\jmath}_C = \sigma \vec E.$$
The ratio between these two currents is
$$ Q = \frac{j_D}{j_C} = \frac{\epsilon \omega}{\sigma} = \frac{k_R}{k_I}.$$
(Incidentally, this is also related to the ration between the real and complex parts of the wave vector $\vec k$ of a plane wave propagating through a conducting medium. The algebra in its derivation is quite tedious so i'll forgo putting it here.)

So it appears we know that:

- When $Q$ approaches infinity, $k_R\gg k_I$, we have a bad conductor. The wave does not get dissipated, it just passes through.
- When $Q$ approaches zero, $k_I\gg k_R$, we have a good conductor. There is a finite skin depth.

Those two statements above I'm not really 100% confident if they're correct. Some other sources say that a good conductor has $Q = 1$. So what does $Q = 1$ imply, or what are the properties of a medium with $Q = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

$Q=1$ means $J_{c} = J_{d}$, no? That's what it looks like to me. $k_{r} = k_{i}$ too, so it will be a perfectly balanced conductor?